# How to monitor HttpWebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#

While there is firebug for monitoring browser activity the best free tool for monitoring visual studio debugging or some custom app seems to be fiddler.

Apart from having configuration issues that might proove quite dificult to solve and having features that are hard to configure, fiddler won't capture traffic when proxyserver is used and have issues with VPN clients. It will miss some https requests and show only some CONNECT requests sometimes, and won't display requests when response times out. Yet worse, fiddler seems to change requests, for example there are some google servers that won't respond at all when fiddler is used.

So I'm looking for a way to log requests within my app directly when they are being sent, and of course I don't want to log the request object, but the real thing thats being sent.

I've tried to use fiddler core API with no success, and I don't like it anyway, it starts a proxy like the tool. Instead I want to capture the request/response comunication in my app, in the same thread synchronously. The HttpWebRequest must implement sockets, so there must be a way to intercept what's going on, but I'm not able to find some good explanation.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: You need packet sniffer like wireshark. This is a sample for C# : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C

Comment: You could try WireShark.  With fiddler the traffic for proxyserver is there but the IP address changes.  Look carefully in fiddler results to find the missing data.  A Proxy Server create a new connection which may be the reason you are not seeing all the messages.

Comment: Why I need to sniff my own app traffic, can't I get intercept that while it's being processed womewhere in some .net objects?

Comment: Are these requests going to a web service?  or is the app in question a web service give more detail please.

Comment: I don't see how that makes any difference since I want to capture the comunication in the same app without starting anything external. Anyway it is a dll that deals with interacting with websites and servers, mostly creating requests over http/https. I don't know if it will be used in a service or anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the .NET level you can enable System.NET tracing/logging. You will get all the information you need (or even more). Sometimes it might be a bit hard to put things together but once you figure this out it all makes sense. [Here is an msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx) article showing how to enable System.NET tracing.

Answer (score 0):

Try GoogleChrome's PostMan extension.
It is very good api testing tool